# Calling method from class issue format input

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Hello guys I have got this method that I need insert data to. I'm not sure in what format I have to provide the input:

[image]

As there is (**string[] dic, out InformaceOplatciType[] statusPlatceDPH**) how should input in `getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce()` look like please?

Thank you so much.

With help of all of you I came up wit this:

```
            string[] ahoj = new string[] { 28156609.ToString() };

        Rozhranice.StatusType[] ahoj2;

        Rozhranice.InformaceOPlatciType[] ahoj3;

        Rozhranice.rozhraniCRPDPH srv = new Rozhranice.rozhraniCRPDPH();



        textBox1.Text = (srv.getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce(ahoj, out ahoj3).ToString());
```

Next issue is that I need to return those fields:

[image]

And when doing `(srv.getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce(ahoj, out ahoj3).ToString());` I'am able to return only fields from `StatusType`, How is that possible I think I will receive `InformaceOPlatciType` ?

[image]

For example like this:

```
textBox1.Text = (srv.getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce(ahoj, out ahoj3).odpovedGenerovana.ToString());
```

I get: the field `odpovedGenerovana` from `StatusType` but I thought that I was calling out `InformaceOPlatciType`

Comment: Don't use images to show code. Post your code directly into the question's body.

Comment: Maybe `new [] {ahoj, ahoj2}`, however it's hard to tell what you want to pass to the method.

Comment: did you check the documentation for the tool/code you are using `Rozhranice`? I would imagine they would have that written somewhere

Comment: (string)1.ToString()???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you EXACTLY what it wants, a string array in and a InformaceOfPlatciType array out.

```
var ahoj = new string[]{ 41354.ToString()};
InformaceOfPlatciType[] ahoj2;

richTextBox1.Text = srv.getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce(ajoh, out ahoj2);
```

In addition, you don't need to cast to type string with (string) if you're calling ToString() of the object in the first place.

Something along these lines.  Though since InformaceOfPlatciType is a custom type, there may be restrictions on what it requires.

Comment: Why do you initialize `ahoj2`?

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't realize it was a custom type when I first posted my answer and I forgot to take out the initialization.  Thanks.

Comment: It's less about being a custom array element type and more about being an `out` parameter that you do not need to initialize `ahoj2`.

Answer (score 0):

The first array needs to be passed as a normal argument; an array that you can create either inline or before, as a variable. For example:

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
```

The second parameter is an `out` parameter, which means an array will be supplied by the method. All you have to do is provide a variable of the appropriate array type that will receive the resulting array:

```
InformaceOPlatciType[] myResults;
```

Then, you can invoke the function like this:

```
srv.getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce(myStrings, out myResults);
```

Note the use of the `out` keyword in the call.

I have no idea what the values in the first array need to look like, because I do not know the class or method you are using, but I suppose you have access to some docs that explain what kind of strings you have to input there.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me alot, can you please see my edit? I have little issue with fields that returns.